# If I register to vote, can I be called for jury duty even though I live abroad?

Tags: usa, elections

I'm a US citizen living abroad. I'd like to register to vote, however I've heard that this will make me eligible to be chosen for jury duty.

I can't easily appear for jury duty from here, if I register for an absentee ballot will I still be obliged to turn up for jury duty?

A reliable reference would be appreciated (but not necessary). I'm getting some conflicting answers via Google, though the majority seem to say that I can ask to be exempt (not entirely sure how this is to be done).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been called to jury duty while living abroad, and had to call them and tell them there was no way I could make it.

It depends on how good the local systems are and how much they know.  I have been selected for jury duty while abroad, and so have two of my siblings.  In these cases it took a quick call to the county clerk to get things straightened out.  No they aren't going to make you travel home (at least in the US) to sit on a jury.

Comment: Any details on who one should call?

Comment: "Undue Hardship" is the term to plea here - the cost of the travel alone is generally going to be sufficient to show it.